# Future Function Returning Null Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a function in order to see which method the user has used to sign in eg. Google. I made a function which was called getProvider(). Here is the code for the function.

```
Future<String> getProvider (FirebaseAuth _auth) 
                              async {
                                var user = await _auth.currentUser();
                                var provider;
                                Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
                                await firestore
                                    .collection('Users')
                                    .document('${user.uid}')
                                    .get()
                                    .then((value) {
                                    provider =
                                    value.data['Authentication Provider'];
                                    return provider;
                                });
                              }
```

However, when I print the output value of the function outside the function itself, I get null.
`print(await getProvider(_auth)) //This prints null`
However, when I print the value of provider inside the function, it is not null and In this case, I get google. When I removed this function and called all of the code wherever I needed it, it worked as expected.

This shows that there is a problem with the return value of this `getProvider()` function. Can someone please let me know how I can fix this so that it actually returns the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future<String> getProvider(FirebaseAuth _auth) async {
  var user = await _auth.currentUser();
  Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
  return firestore
      .collection('Users')
      .document('${user.uid}')
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.data['Authentication Provider']);
}
```

`then()` returns a `Future` which you can later `await` on to get the value. Since your method are already returning `Future<String>` you should be able to just return the `Future` generated by `then()`.

Comment: Thanks though could you explain how that worked? I didn't really get it

Comment: `then()` is just another way to use `await`. `then()` is used to give a callback method which are called when the value from your `Future` are eventually ready. The result from the callback are then returned as another `Future` which are the `Future` you get from calling `then()`.

Comment: When you mark a method as `async` it will automatically pack your code into `then()` every time you are using `await`. Therefore your method must therefore end up returning `Future<T>` and in this case `Future<String>`.

Comment: So, since we know `then()` are returning `Future<String>` in this case, it is fully valid to just return this `Future`. Alternative, you could have used `await` like you have done with `await _auth.currentUser()` to get the `String` and then return the `String`.

Comment: I have also updated my solution to simplify your code a little and removed unnecessary variables.